# How to replicate this blog listing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to build a news theme for wordpress and one of the requirements is that I need to display groups of news items by categories as are shown on most newssites - the quoted example is of the site [www.chicagotribune.com](http://www.chicagotribune.com)

From the site you can see that on the home page all the main categories are listed and each category group has some news articles listed and has one article with a picture.

I'm using a simple logic here that to select 6 latest news articles of each category and the latest one would be the main highlight i.e show a picture or one which has a featured image if the latest article doesnt have a picture.

I've customized wordpress themes before however I need an idea of how to do this right here - what functions should I be looking at and how can I actually run a loop that goes like:

Loop through all subcategories and within each subcategory loop through latest 6 articles if the page is a category page

Loop through all main categories and within each main category loop through latest 6 articles if home page

any ideas guys?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories would be a good place to start.

Comment: Ok but what about selecting those stories which have an image or featured image story - plus is there any way to ensure that I don't end up repeating stories on the page?

Comment: Once you have your categories loop through those and use get_posts() to retrieve your posts and sort them appropriately.  Then loop through the posts and use the post thumbnail functions for your images.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

You can use some custom wp-query and widget area in your homepage like [This genesis child theme](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/news/)